# JTextField positioning/layout issues

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, jtextfield

I've been working on a dialog window for a desktop app I'm currently developing. The dialog has to have a pre-specified number of text fields (in other words variable), but I encountered a weird error when coding the initialization part of the code: When the JTextField components are initialized the last one decides to take up the whole window. I've tried many and weird ways to change the way it is added to the window, but it keeps doing this no matter what (btw I set the default texts to the fields' indexes so that I know it's always the last one). Here's the code:

```
package com.main;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.TextField;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class classAddingDialog extends startingMenuWindow {

    private JFrame frame1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    classAddingDialog window = new classAddingDialog();
                    window.frame1.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public classAddingDialog() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        int count = 18,i;                                                                             //startingMenuWindow.countForNewClass;
        frame1.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 20+50*count/2+50);
        TextField[] nameInputs=new TextField[count];

        for(i=0;i<count;i++) {
            nameInputs[i]=new TextField();
            if(i<Math.ceil((double) count/2)) {
                nameInputs[i].setBounds(10, 10+50*i, 100, 30);
            }else {
                nameInputs[i].setBounds(180, (int) (10+50*(i-Math.ceil((double) count/2))), 100, 30);
            }
            nameInputs[i].setText(Integer.toString(i));
            frame1.add(nameInputs[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also don't put effort in checking the last JTextField's position and bounds, I already did and the

```
nameInputs[i].getBounds();
```

function returns the correct position (where it should be), but in reality it just covers the whole Window.

If someone knows what the problem is, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the JTextField components are initialized the last one decides to take up the whole window.

Swing uses layout managers. The default layout manager for the content pane of the JFrame is the BorderLayout. When you don't specify a constraint the component gets added to the BorderLayout.CENTER of the frame. Only one component can be added to the CENTER and that is the last one you add. The rules of the BorderLayout then state the component in the CENTER takes up all the remaining space in the frame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples of using the BorderLayout.

The solution is to NOT attempt to set the bounds of your components and instead use layout managers.

1. Don't use TextField, that is an AWT component. You should be using `JTextField`
2. When you create the JTextField use something like `new JTextField(10)`. The 10 will specify the number of "W" characters that can be displayed in the text field at one time. This allows the text field to calculate its preferred size which can then be used by the layout managers.
3. Don't try to assign the bounds of the text field. Swing was designed to be used with a layout manager. The layout manager will determine the size and location of the component based on the rules of the layout manager.
4. It looks to me like you are attempting to display the text fields in a two column grid, so you can use a panel with a `GridLayout`. See the tutorial for examples.

So your basic logic would be something like:

```
JPanel grid = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 2) );

for(i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
    textField.setText( Integer.toString(i) );
    nameInputs[i] = textField();
    grid.add( textField ):
}

frame.add(grid);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you're a god. Even my teacher who has a decent experience in java couldn't find what the reason was.